# Is it possible to move an iframes content higher?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe that I am using from emailmeform.com and what I want to do is to have the content of the iframe (the form) to be "cropped" in the iframe so it start at a certain point.

The reason for this is that the iframe that they give you have a certain amount of space at the top and it makes my webpage look messy. I want to higher the form so I can close the gap between my iframe and my text

I've used stackoverflow.com as mock iframe content as the form I am using has personal info:

```
    <iframe height="1258" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%; border:none" src="http://stackoverflow.com/">
    <a href=
    "http://stackoverflow.com/">Fill out form.</a></iframe>
```

Comment: hm... not if is cross domain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `style` attribute to your iframe like this

```
<iframe src="blahblab" style="position:relative; top:-200px;"></iframe>
```

then the content of your `iframe` will display content in 200px offset top.